# regex greedy problem (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, greedy, regex-greedy

I've a input string like "===text=== and ===text===" and I want to replace wiki syntax with the corresponding html tag.

input:

```
===text=== and ===text===
```

desirable output:

```
<h1>text</h2> and <h1>text</h2>
```

but with the following code I get this output:

```
var regex = new Regex("---(.+)---");
var output = regex.Replace("===text=== and ===text===", "<h1>$1</h1>");

<h1>text=== and ===text</h1>
```

I know the problem is that my regex matches greedy. But how to make them non greedy.

Thank you and kind regards. Danny

Comment: Try this on for size: http://regexr.com?2t9he

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the [question mark](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) to your regex: ===(.+?)===

A better alternative would be to have a regex of the following form: ===([^\=]+)===.
See [this guide](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) on the dot character for an explanation of using the dot sparingly. When benchmarking my supplied regex, it is approx. 50% faster than your regex.

Answer (score 3):

To make a Regex not greedy you use ?

So the expression "===(.+?)===" would have two matches for you - so should allow you to generate `<h1>text</h1>` and `<h1>text</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply dd a `?` maybe?

```
===.+?===
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another variant: `===((?:(?!===).)*)===` (stop catching any character when you encounter `===`)... Oh... and for the `.` problem suggested by WiseGuyEh, I suggest RegexOptions.SingleLine, so that the `.` match even the newline.

Answer (score 0):

And just for info if others have the same issue then I had - to avoid matching also `====Text====` instead of `===Text===` I've extended the pattern like this: `(?<!=)===([^=]+)===(?!=)`