# Regular expression : Find elements wrapped with specific selectors

Tags: php, regex

I'm really bad with regular expressions - never had enough time to learn it properly.

I'm trying to find all elements within the string which are wrapped with %% %% - example would be:

> %%gallery%%

Any idea what regular expression would do the job here?

I'm going to later use it in PHP to replace the placeholders with relevant plugins.

Comment: `/%%(.+?)%%/s` would match that, for example. If you need more suitable/precise answers, you'd have to give more information on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at: [regex greedy problem (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275904/regex-greedy-problem-c)

`(?<!%)%%([^%]+)%%(?!%)`

This matches exactly %%anything%%. It's non greedy an match also correctly content like 'Lorem ipsum %%sample%% lorem %%%ipsum%%% and so on'.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace("/%%\w+%%/", "replacement", "string");
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like `/%%[a-z]+%%/i` would work.

The `[a-z]+` part tells there should be multiple characters (+) between a-z, surrounded with %'s. The /i makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

One regex would be:

```
%%(.*?)%%
```

As in:

```
$string = preg_replace('/%%(.*?)%%/', '{replacement for $1}', $string);
```

`.*` matches "anything" and `?` makes it a non-greedy match, which means it tries to find as short a match as possible. If you have a string like `"%%a%% %%b%%"` you don't want it to find the *longest* match possible which would be `a%% %%b`.

```
%%a%% %%b%%         # Greedy
  ^^^^^^^

%%a%% %%b%%         # Non-greedy
  ^     ^
```

The `$1` in the replacement string is whatever the matched tag is. In your example that'd be the word `gallery`.