# Find text wrapped by specific characters and use that text as a parameter for a function

Tags: php, regex, function, replace, find

I'm outputting some HTML from a database to a page, containing constructions like this:

```
<p>Department: *|accounting|*</p>
```

I would like to find and replace all text wrapped with *| and |* and use the word in between as a variable for my translate function.

I've found a [partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326692/regular-expression-find-elements-wrapped-with-specific-selectors). Could you guys help me out with the rest? Thanks.

This is somewhat what I'm looking for...

```
$html_from_database = "<p>Department: *|accounting|*</p>";

$updated_html = preg_replace("*|(.*?)|*", translate('accounting'),$html_from_database);
```

Is something like this possible? What about the regex? Is it not too resource intensive or to greedy? Please note that the only characters between *| and |* will be a-z A-Z -_ 0-9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I just tested it and it works:

```
preg_match_all('/\|(.*?)\|/', $source, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    $source = str_replace($match,translate($match),$source);
}
```

`$source` is your source text.

Comment: Thanks, it works and translates well. Only problem is that $source is still wrapped in *| and |*. How can we tweak it? 

[edit: the star symbol doesn't display in comments apparently...]

Comment: Use `foreach($matches[1] as $mid => $match) $source = str_replace($matches[0][$mid],translate($match),$source);` instead then.

Comment: Thanks, man! This works. I just updated the regex a little bit, because you're version doesn't take into account the star symbol (which for some reasons I cannot put in comments...)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two steps, find the matches, then call the translate function on each one and build up the resulting string. Something like this pseudocode:

```
matches = preg_find(".*(\|([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)\|).*", sourceHtml)
foreach match in matches
    outputHtml += sourceHtml(section between previous match and this one)
    outputHtml += translate(inner group from match)
    record end position of match
outputHtml += end of sourceHtml
```